# Get value of inputs with Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have 100 inputs with the name `table[]`. How can I get their value with jQuery, as an array?

I am trying to do something like `$_POST['table']` in PHP.

I tried the following code, but I want the values as an array...

```
$("input[name='table[]']").each(function(){document.write($(this).val());});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var arrInputValues = new Array();
$("input[name='table\\[\\]']").each(function(){
     arrInputValues.push($(this).val()); 
     // you can also use this
     //arrInputValues.push(this.value);
});
```

Now your arrInputValues contains all the value.

You can also use

```
$("input[name='table[]']").each(function(){
```

You can see a **[working demo](http://jsbin.com/unima3)**

You can use join() method to join the values in the array.

```
arrInputValues.join(',');
```

will join the array elements as a string separated by `,`.

Comment: document.write(arrInputValues) outputs test1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,test2 and so on.
Is this normal?

Comment: Thank you!
And how to unjoin them?
Will it work if I process the string through foreach in PHP and insert it in DB.
Do You see my answer below?

Comment: You can split the string in php using the `,` and get the values. But you have to be careful when choosing the delimiter. Any of the values should not contain the delimiter character.

Answer (score 3):

Following code gives the ***value*** of each input

```
 var arr=new Array();
 $("input[name='table[]']").each(function()
 {  
    var val=$(this).attr('value');
    document.write(val);
    arr.Push(val);
 });
```

Comment: Can You tell me how to get the value for all elements as array?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

the [ and ] characters are special characters, you need to escape them

```
$("input[name='table\\[\\]']").each(function()
 {  document.write($(this).val());           });
```

Comment: OK,but how to get it as array?
Now it outputs me that:
test1test2test3test4........
How to get is like
Array (
[0] => test1
    [1] => test2
    [2] => test3
    [3] => test4
)

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `[]` chars, try this:

```
$("input[name='table\\[\\]']").each(function()
 ...........
```

Comment: As I post above
OK,but how to get it as array? Now it outputs me that: test1test2test3test4........ How to get is like Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => test2 [2] => test3 [3] => test4 )

Comment: @Angelov: It is already an array in $_POST['table']; you can see the contents of that like print_r($_POST['table']);

Comment: I didn't explain it right.
The ide of this all is that I want to transfer the value of the input to another file ,using AJAX,where I will submit that value in BD ,but I must use foreach ,which,I think expects array.

foreach($_POST['table'] AS $data) {
//THE INSERT TO THE DB
}
I want to insert it without refreshing the page,while clicking submit ,thats why I use AJAX.
But to happen the submission to the DB I must sent the data to the another file ,using AJAX.Thats why I want to make the array in JS.After this I will serialize it to a string and do what I want