# how to get checkbox values from div

Tags: jquery, html

how to get checkbox values from div

```
<div id="panel">
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td><input  type="checkbox" value="option1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input  type="checkbox" value="option2" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

i have tried following way value came like

```
var listofParameters = $('panel :input')
for (var index in listofParameters) {
    var ste = $(listofParameters[index]).val();
```

also not get full value

if checkbox value is . Sales Manager , i got sales only in value

Finally i got this issue too "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'toLowerCase' of undefined or null reference "

Comment: you missed the id selector: `#`. eg `$('#panel input')`

Comment: What end-result do you want, an array of values, or something else?

Comment: There is no need to use a normal `for` loop with jQuery objects. Have a look at `.each`: http://api.jquery.com/each/. You can solve some things more elegantly if you make full use of jQuery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get value of inputs with Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393561/get-value-of-inputs-with-jquery)

Comment: Hi , i have tried # to i got values as "On" but i don't have values on   actually i added like that <input  type="checkbox" >option2</i put>

Comment: *"also not get full value"* A checkbox has only one value, the `value` attribute. If you don't want to get that, then you have to post an example of the HTML and explain what you want. You didn't post the code where you try to use `toLowerCase`, so we cannot really help you with that. But the error message is clear, isn't it? Please update your question with the appropriate information.

Answer (score 1):

You missed `#`

```
var listofParameters = $('#panel :input')
     for (var index in listofParameters) {
        var ste = $(listofParameters[index]).val();
```

Comment: thanks for answer , after white space not get text value

Answer (score 0):

A valid selector is  `$('#panel :input')`

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
var listofParameters = $('panel :input')
```

with

```
var listofParameters = $('#panel :input')
```

You missed the selector `#`

Answer (score 0):

```
var listofParameters = $('#panel :input')
for (var index in listofParameters) {
   var ste = $(listofParameters[index]).val();
```

Comment: i got ste values "on" only . also got exception can't get toLowercase ..

Answer (score 0):

```
var listofParameters = $('#panel input:checkbox')
for (var index in listofParameters) {
   var ste = $(listofParameters[index]).val();
```

Making the selector specific to the checkbox type only.